# Matching all tokens in a Multivalued Field in Solr

Tags: php, solr, tokenize

I'm trying an approach to resolve a search requirement by tokenizing a serial string into individual terms inside of a multivalued field. 
basically, each document may contain multiple values for searching. 
a user search can match against any value inside of a multivalued field, however, all terms must match the values of the individual item inside of that multivalued field. 
So here is my setup

I have a field type,lets call it "tokensearch"

```
<fieldType name="tokensearch" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\|\s*" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
       <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\ \s*" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

a sample data field will be

```
<arr name="tokensearch">
    <str>a:3|b:3|c:3|d:5|e:5</str>
    <str>a:1|b:3|c:5|d:4|e:2</str>
    <str>a:2|b:3|c:3|d:2|e:1</str>
</arr>
```

this will basically create a multidimensional array in solr, so that  it looks somethign like so

```
a[0]=array(a:3,b:3,c:3..)
a[1] = array(a:1,b:3,c:5..)
```

that part is working as it should, however when I perform a search for `"a:1 c:5"`
what should happen is my queryparser should say is give me fields where a an individual item of the top array contains both a:1 and c:5

right now, its working as long as they appear in order "a:1 b:3 c:5" will match array[1], however "a:1 c:5" will not .

So that is my setup, my goal is to have a specifiable combination of values within the multivalued field where all tokens passed must match.

my query at the moment is very simple 
q=tokensearch:"a:1 c:3"

i've tried playing with query but that seems to be the closest to what I need
q=tokensearch:"a:1" tokensearch:"c:3"&q.op=AND - returns docs what contain a:1 and c:3 in different entries of multivalued array

If you need further info on what i'm attempting please let me know. if you have any idea how to make this work so that I dont have to specify the tokens in exact order that would be great.

ALSO : when I do a field analyzer it does match my tokens out of order so I'm a bit confuzed why it wont during real search

Comment: I've resoved this using word gap, seems to do the trick q=tokensearch:"a:1 c:3"~2 works